# How do i create a regular expression that append all my style selectors with a id

Tags: html, css, regex

I am creating something wherein i have to add some css and html content to a div with an id #resultContainer, now this css and html is input by the user in textboxes, and i am using jquery to retrieve their values and append them to the #resultContainer but the problem is i want to append the styles with the prefix #resultContainer

like i want to replace the string -

```
p {...
}
p i{...
}
```

to

```
#resultContainer p{...
}
#resultContainer p i{...
}
```

Is there a way to do this, either by using regular expressions or is there a way to apply any css rules i write to that #resultContainer only and not outside that....

Comment: How are you acquiring that string?

Comment: @acdcjunior: In the question, it says that it's from user input.

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah, I read it. Yet, I find that too broad to draw any conclusions. Maybe it is a single line input, maybe it is a textarea with several line breaks, maybe there are several inputs, maybe half of it is input, half of it is appended by a script. Without clearing that, all we can do is guess.

Comment: sorry for that part, i wanted to give all the info , but that would be really irrelevant for the solution i was looking for, thats why i thought that this much info was sufficient enough for what i was trying to achieve , but sorry if you felt lack of info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick regex that seems to work:

```
/(.+)(?={)/g
```

Try it like this:

```
yourCSS.replace(/(.+)(?={)/g, '#resultContainer $1');
```

Here's a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Rf53/